# How do i Use a PCL project to develop an app for Android and iOS in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin PCL project, it has Android iOS and Portable. I had a look at few examples, where in you can create a Login Page using `Xaml` and then validate those credentials using a CS file for it,but my question is lets say I validate those credentials, how do I jump from that UI page which is universal I suppose to the Android or the iOS part?

And where do I start ??

Sorry if I am being naive, I am new to Xamarin, any help would be appreciated.

This is the sample i'm referring for Portable,

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StoreCredentials
{
    public class HomePageCS : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePageCS ()
        {
            var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem {
                Text = "Logout"
            };
            toolbarItem.Clicked += OnLogoutButtonClicked;
            ToolbarItems.Add (toolbarItem);

            Title = "Home Page";
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Main app content goes here",
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        async void OnLogoutButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<ICredentialsService> ().DeleteCredentials ();
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new LoginPage (), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: generally, if you are using Xamarin Forms, you will build your entire UI using XF.  If there are specific pages where you need to expose platform specific UI, then you can do that with Custom Renderers or DI.

Comment: could you tell me any example ??

Comment: xamarin has dozens of samples on their website

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/) before diving into Xamarin.
Also, [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/) as it relates to something you are trying to do.